# How to convert HTML/javascript into MVC web application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have [this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jerred/r1u5Le2t/1/), which I want to convert into a visual studio MVC web application.

```
`function draw(){

//
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

// draw connecting lines
for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    var c=connectors[i];
    var s=anchors[c.start];
    var e=anchors[c.end];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(s.x,s.y);
    ctx.lineTo(e.x,e.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}   

// draw circles
for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(anchors[i].x,anchors[i].y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill(); 
    ctx.fillText(anchors[i].label,anchors[i].x-5,anchors[i].y-15); 
}
}`
```

I already tried [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model) but I can't fully understand.

Hopefully someone can give me the step by step procedure specifically on the given code in jsfiddle.Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with the web application? Given this is all JavaScript, you currently don't need C#.NET at all.

Comment: I want to convert it into a MVC web application.

Comment: I guess that you want to create MVC app that will display some view with model which should be used by your Javascript to draw on canvas?

Comment: @Piotr exactly that's what I need.

Comment: Not really clear what you waning to do but you can create a HtmlHelper extension method that generates the canvas and its shapes and then use it as (say) `@Html.DrawSomething(someParameters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create model with List of points
2. Send it to View
3. Transfer model to JavaScript object
4. Use it in your script

Ad 1. `/<MvcApp>/Models/Model.cs`

```
public  class Model 
{
   public IEnumerable<Point> Points {get; set;}
}
```

Ad 2. in Razor view: `/<MvcApp>/Views/<ControllerName>/<ActionName>.cshtml`

```
@model <model_namespace>.Model
```

Ad 3. Prepare helper to convert model to javascript object
file:

```
/<MvcApp>/Helpers/HtmlJsonExtension.cs
```

code:

```
public static class HtmlJsonExtension
{
    public static IHtmlString ToJson(this HtmlHelper helper, object obj)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };
        settings.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
        return helper.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings));
    }
}
```

remember to register it in: `/<MvcApp>/Views/web.config`

and later use it to convert C# model to Javascript object in razor view: `/<MvcApp>/Views/<ControllerName>/<ActionName>.cshtml`

```
var javascriptPoints = Html.ToJson(Model.Points);  // <-- should return array of points
```

4. Pass `javascriptPoints` to your drawing logic

Comment: The Ad.2 will be put in what exact file?

Comment: If you have let say controller named Board with action  Draw then you should have corresponded view file ~/View/Board/Draw.cshtml For experiments try put your javascript drawing logic into this file. later you can extract it [js logic] to separate js file.

Comment: Is it ok to identify the specific file name in every step ?

Comment: I added files to answer

Comment: I can't follow :( sorry I am new in MVC.

Comment: @model <MvcApp>.Models.Model.cs  -> <MvcApp> == your project name

Comment: Is it possible to upload your project in github?

Comment: I thought it will be the same with jsfiddle output :(

Comment: Repo updated. Check it out
https://github.com/ppasieka/Sample/blob/master/Sample/Sample/Views/Board/Draw.cshtml